# MS Project 2019 scheduling algorithm

Tags: scheduling, ms-project

Whats resource constrained scheduling algorithm is used by MS Project 2019? What RCPSP algorithm is behind a so called a resources leveling in MS Project 2019?

Comment: As this question is not about programming, but rather how to use Microsoft Project, it belongs on the [Project Management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/) or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) site.

Comment: I ask about applied algorithm,  in order to improve it.

Comment: I take it another way around. So many users of MS Project and nobody knowns the algorithm used for scheduling because is proprietary?

Comment: JackAW, As Rachel noted, your question is in the wrong part of the forum. Please re-post to the Project Management site. Also, if you have a suggestion for improvement, in the Project app you can go to, Feedback > "I have a suggestion"

Comment: @RachelHettinger so far not answered in another group: https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/34826/ms-project-2019-or-lower-scheduling-algorithm

Comment: Pretty sure the exact algorithm is proprietary. But there are plenty of articles explaining how MS Project works (at a high level). Are you looking to build your own scheduling tool?

Comment: @RachelHettinger yes, it is proprietary. But question is what sort of algorithm it is. Is it a branch and bound, mixed integer programming based, heuristic based, metaheuristic, or some exotic? Yes, I designed some new scheduling algorithm. I would like to combine it with my project portfolio selection tool.